# Dump text with some code in it to yaml document with SnakeYAML

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I'm trying to dump text, which containes some code, also with TAB's(\t) into yaml file with SnakeYAML.

When i yaml.load() this yaml file everything happens as expected.

> file.yaml

`local: |
 begin
     if P_MESSAGE = 'DEFAULT' then
         P_FILE.[SRC_TYPE] := true;
 end;`

> Test.js

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);

Map<String, Object> test = yaml.load(new FileInputStream(new File("file.yaml"));

System.out.println(test);
```

> Output:

`{local=begin
   if P_MESSAGE = 'DEFAULT' then
       P_FILE.[SRC_TYPE] := true;
end;}`

But when i try to dump this string back to file

> Test.js

```
...
Map<String, Object> test = yaml.load(new FileInputStream(new File("file.yaml"));

String out = yaml.dump(test);
System.out.println(out);
```

i've got this:

> Output

`"local": "begin\n    if P_MESSAGE = 'DEFAULT' then\n\t\tP_FILE.[SRC_TYPE] := true;\n\
end;`

I want to get it back with original formatting scalar, like in first block. I want for example \t to be real tab. Does anyone have a hint?

Settings:

`options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.AUTO);
 options.setDefaultScalarStyle(DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.LITERAL);`